# Windows service not seen in services even after successful installation

Tags: c#, installation, operating-system, windows-services

There is one windows service which is installed on one of our servers and working fine.

I tried to replicate the same on the other server, so I took the exe setup from one server to another and tried to install the windows service using installUtil.exe
It is giving me

> The Commit phase was completed successfully. The transacted install has been completed.

but the service cannot be found in the services list and it is also giving me this message at the time of installation.

> No public installers with the RunInstallerAttribute.Yes, the attribute could be found in the xyz.exe assembly.
> Remove InstallState file because there are no installers.

and I am not sure why this is happening? I tried googling but most of them have given the solution to add installer to the project.
But if the installer is not added how the service is running on the first server
is there another way to install the service?
Could it be related to the Windows OS version?

Comment: can you show code in installer file ??

Comment: I just have an exe which was used last to install the windows service

Comment: Do you have all supporting files? Copy all files from last install and if still not worked copy all files from bin folder of your source code (issue might be because of Install log files )

Comment: Also try by removing .InstallLog and .InstallState Files